# Can't enable logging for Bind 9 on Red Hat

Tags: linux, bind, selinux

When I enable logging for Bind, I get a permissions denied error which is due to Bind running in chroot/selinux (avc denied write). I can't figure out how to reconfigure selinux to allow the log file to be writeable. Please could someone help?

Thank you!!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Try restoring the context on the file (as root):

```
touch /var/log/file # if it doesn't already exist
restorecon -v /var/log/file
```

For more info, this should help: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux